# How can I print the name of Dataframe and check row and column in Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem about showing the name of Dataframe and check row and column in Dataframe in Python.

Here is my dataframes with rows and columns.

```
print("x_train: ",x_train.shape)
print("x_test: ",x_test.shape)
print("y_train: ",y_train.shape)
print("y_test: ",y_test.shape)
```

Output is shown below.

```
x_train:  (30, 455)
x_test:  (30, 114)
y_train:  (455,)
y_test:  (114,)
```

I wrote a code snippt shown below to show the name of Dataframe and rows and columns of Dataframe.
It throws `tuple out of range` because `y_train` and `y_test` has no column.

```
    def showRowsandColumns(value):
    name =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is value][0]
    if not isinstance(value, pd.DataFrame):
        value = value.to_frame()
    if not value.shape[0] and  value.shape[1]:
        value_count_row = value.shape[0]  # gives number of row count
        value_count_col = value.shape[1]  # gives number of col count
    elif value.shape[0] and not value.shape[1]:
        value_count_row = value.shape[0]  # gives number of row count
        value_count_col = 0
    elif not value.shape[0] and value.shape[1]:
        value_count_row = 0  # gives number of row count
        value_count_col = value.shape[1]
    else:
        value_count_row = value.shape[0]  # gives number of row count
        value_count_col = value.shape[1]  # gives number of col count
    print("{} : {} rows and {} columns "
          .format(name,value_count_row,value_count_col))

showRowsandColumns(x_train)
showRowsandColumns(x_test)
showRowsandColumns(y_train)
showRowsandColumns(y_test)
```

the error is :

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_frame'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is throwing error for y_train and y_test, because they are not DataFrames, they are in deed Series. You see that by their shape. If you want you can do print(type(y_test)))  and it will show that they are in deed Series and not DataFrames.

One of the easiest ways is simply convert the y_test and y_train  to DataFrame before passing it to your method:

```
 y_test = y_test.to_frame()
 showRowsandColumns(y_test)
```

You do this for only the series ( in your case y_test, y_train )

Make a note that these are changed to DataFrme so you need to handle it appropriately down the line.

Here is an example:

```
y = df['col5']
print(y.shape)
print(type(y))
print(y.ndim)

(4,)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1
```

I convert this Series to DF:

```
y = y.to_frame()
y.shape
```

I call your function:

```
showRowsandColumns(y)

4 rows and 1 columns
```

Comment: So you have numpy.ndarrays and not DataFrames as you stated in your original question. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the number of rows and columns, then pandas.DataFrame.shape returns a tuple containing (rows, columns)

Comment: My question is based on how to fix the issue in function. I already knew shape function